# Is there way to bind queue to default exchange explicitly in RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messaging, rabbitmq-exchange

I made a mistake: now both of two queues are explicitly bound to some exchange, which i can edit for every queue. One of those queues must be bound to default exchange. Now when i try to change exchange of that queue to empty string, it throws an exception:

`Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - operation not permitted on the default exchange, class-id=<..>, method-id=<..>)`

Can i pass some specific values to method com.rabbitmq.client.Channel#queueBind to bind queue to defaultChange?
I use Java RabbitMQ client library 5.6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we need to understand what a default exchange is;

From [RabbitMQ Docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-default)

> The default exchange is a direct exchange with no name (empty string)
>   pre-declared by the broker. It has one special property that makes it
>   very useful for simple applications: every queue that is created is
>   automatically bound to it with a routing key which is the same as the
>   queue name.

So basically, in other words, if you create a queue with no explicit exchange binding, the queue will have an automatic binding created with the default exchange.

In your question, from your description, it looks like you have two queues (lets say A and B) and you have accidentally bound both the queues to an exchange (lets say test.exchange). Instead of doing changes to the "default.exchange", what you should do is remove the **binding** of queue A or B with your exchange *test.exchange*.

Please check "/api/bindings" related apis on [rabbitMQ Api Guides](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/) or you could simply login to the rabbit management console and remove the binding as well.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i didn't know about that power of rabbit management console. Now we made hotfix and did re-deploy applications, so problem is gone. But i will keep in mind usability of  console if i will got a problem with rabbitMQ